# expected initializer before 'RF24'

Tags: nrf24l01+

The code i make is this 
    */

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;
int servoy;
int servox;
Servo Yservo; 
Servo Xservo; 

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

int joystick[2];

void setup()RF24
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipe);
  radio.startListening();
  Xservo.attach(3);
  Yservo.attach(5);
}

void loop()
{
  if ( radio.available() )
  {
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
done = radio.read( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );
servox= joystick[0]/5.683; 
servoy= joystick[1]/5.683;    
      Serial.println(servoy);
      Yservo.write(servoy);
      Serial.println(servox);
      Xservo.write(servox);
    }
  }
  else
  {    
      Serial.println("NO RADIO CONECTION");
  }

}
```

and i don't know what  happen it's said that

```
 sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22:33:13: error: expected initializer before 'RF24'

 void setup()RF24

             ^

C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Arduino\sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22\sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22:51:6: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

 done = radio.read( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );

      ^

exit status 1
expected initializer before 'RF24'
```

Comment: It's basically saying "Why have you got a random "RF24" in the middle of your code like that?" - and I'm asking the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

```
sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22:33:13: error: expected initializer before 'RF24'

void setup()RF24

         ^
```

It's basically saying "I don't understand what you mean by RF24 here". That `RF24` in that line should not exist. I assume you made some kind of typo or copy-pasta error.

Second:

C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Arduino\sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22\sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22.ino: In function 'void loop()':

```
sketch_aug20b_rc_rc_rc_22:51:6: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

 done = radio.read( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );
```

That is saying that `radio.read` doesn't return a value - yet you are trying to assign that value that doesn't exist to something.

According to the documentation for `RF24::read()`:

> Read the available payload
>
> The size of data read is the fixed payload size, see getPayloadSize()
>
> **Note**
>
> I specifically chose 'void*' as a data type to make it easier for beginners to use. No casting needed.
>
> No longer boolean. Use available to determine if packets are available. Interrupt flags are now cleared during reads instead of when calling available().
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `buf`   Pointer to a buffer where the data should be written
> - `len`   Maximum number of bytes to read into the buffer
>
>   if(radio.available()){
>      radio.read(&data,sizeof(data));
>     }
>
> **Returns**
>
> No return value. Use available().